# Java- Fantasy Sports Draft

Tags: java, arrays

Having a bit of issue here: 
Question(input): complete the function draftPick(). function takes two arguments: an array of integers **teams** representing the order of teams and how many spots they have to fill, and an integer i that determines which team in the order (zero-indexed) we want to know the last pick for.

Output: function should return an integer representing which player the **ith** team in the draft order (zero-indexed) will select with their last pick

Expected runtime: O(n)

**sample input:** lineArray = [5, 1, 2]
position = 2

**sample output:** 5

Explanation: call the tree teams A, B, C. The draft has team A picking first and trying to fill 5 roster spots, team B picking second and filling 1 roster spot, and team C picking last and filling 2 roster spots:

turn 1: A picks 1st best player
turn 2: B picks 2nd best player
turn 3: team C picks 3rd best player
turn 4: team A picks again and get 4th best player
turn 5: since team b has already filled all their roster spots, team C picks 5th best player (THUS THE ANSWER 5)

**Attempt**: trying to develop an algorithm - i see that the ith team for example in [5,1,2] this team has 2 spots to fill. we know that the order of play he picks depends on the number of players in the other elements. i tried traversing the array subtracting (-1) from each element from i=0 to i

Comment: Have you tried something? If yes, could you post some code?

Comment: ive been trying to develop an algorithm - it seems like it can be solved with DP since we have to keep track of how many picks every team currently has. Not sure though - really stuck :/

Comment: Then post your attempt along with your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's an algorithm that I made that suffices according to my testing:

```
int draftPick(int[] teams, int target) {

    int targetTeam = teams[target];
    int finalPick = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i <= target; i++) {

        int team = teams[i];

        if(team > targetTeam) team = targetTeam;

        finalPick += team;

    }

    for(int i = (target + 1); i < teams.length; i++) {

        int team = teams[i];

        if(team > targetTeam - 1) team = targetTeam - 1;

        finalPick += team;

    }

    return finalPick;

}
```